# How to Remove Images in Jenkins Shell Script

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, devops

Parameter Tagging :

```
parameters([
    string(name: 'Version_Major', defaultValue: '1', description: 'Version Major'),
    string(name: 'Version_Minor', defaultValue: '0', description: 'Version Minor'),
    string(name: 'Version_Patch', defaultValue: '0', description: 'Version Patch')
])

stage ('Build Docker images') {
        sh "cd /home/admin/file && docker build -t Image_abcdef:${Version_Major}.${Version_Minor}.${Version_Patch} . "
```

---

### These images are already created on my docker

- Images Name     |      Tag
- Image_abcdef    |     1.0.8
- Image_abcdef    |     1.0.7

if I build images, it will automatically delete the last images.
It will be like this :

- Images Name     |      Tag
- Image_abcdef    |     1.0.9
- Image_abcdef    |     1.0.8

any suggestion for me ?

Thanks before

Comment: Jenkins does not delete Docker images by itself. Do you have any other `docker` commands in this pipeline? Or do you have any other clean-up tasks running on the Jenkins machine? Are all these steps running locally on the Jenkins master, or do you use different agents (docker images are stored per machine, so if you run on different agents, you'll see different images being present).

Comment: Please edit your question and choose your tags more selectively, as this has nothing to do with kubernetes